# Me ajudem com esse código do while e switch em C?

Tags: c, while, switch

Bom fiz esse código na faculdade, em que ele recebe dois números inteiros e conforme a escolha do Usuário ele realiza uma operação aritmética com esses dois números digitados. Acredito que minha lógica esteja correta,ele compila porém não completa sua devida função. Deve haver apenas um erro de sintaxe que está comprometendo o código por completo. Me ajudem por favor ! vale nota essa atividade.
Segue abaixo o código.

````
```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>


main(){
 int n1,n2,res,opc;
 float resu;

 do{
    printf("\nDigite o primeiro numero inteiro :\n");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("\nDigite o segundo numero inteiro :\n");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    system("cls");
    printf("\nMENU DE OPCOES");        
    printf("\n0.sair");
    printf("\n1.soma dos dois numeros");   
    printf("\n2.subtracao do primeiro pelo segundo");   
    printf("\n3.subtracao do segundo pelo primeiro");   
    printf("\n4.multiplicacao dos dois numeros");   
    printf("\n5.divisao do primeiro pelo segundo");   
    printf("\n6.divisao do segundo pelo primeiro");   
    printf("\n7.quociente inteiro da divisao do primeiro pelo segundo");   
    printf("\n8.quociente inteiro da divisao do segundo pelo primeiro");   
    printf("\n9.resto da divisao do primeiro pelo segundo");   
    printf("\n10.resto da divisao do segundo pelo primeiro");   
    printf("\n11.o primeiro elevado pelo segundo");
    printf("\n12.o segundo elevado pelo primeiro");
    printf("\nDigite o numero da opcao desejada :\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    system("cls");

 switch (opc){
 case 1 : 
        res=n1+n2;
        printf("O resultado da soma eh: %d",res);    
        break;
   case 2 :
        res=n1-n2;
        printf("O resultado da subtracao eh: %d",res);          
        break;     
   case 3 :
        res=n2-n1;
        printf("O resultado da subtracao eh: %d",res);
        break;
   case 4 :
        res=n1*n2;
        printf("O resultado da multiplicacao eh: %d",res);
        break;
   case 5 :
        if (n1 ==0){
        printf("Divisao por 0 !");  
        }
        else{
        resu =(float) n1/n2;
        printf("O resultado da divisao eh: %.2f",resu);
        }
        break;
   case 6 :
        if (n2 == 0){
        printf("Divisao por 0 !");  
        }
        else{
        resu =(float) n2/n1;
        printf("O resultado da divisao eh: %.2f",resu);
        }
        break;
   case 7 :
        res = n1 - ((n1/n2) * n2);
        printf("O quociente da divisao eh : %d",res);
        break;
   case 8 :
        res = n2 - ((n2/n1) * n1);
        printf("O quociente da divisao eh : %d",res);
        break;
   case 9 :
        res=n1%n2;
        printf("O resto da divisao eh: %d",res);
        break;
   case 10 :
        res=n2%n1;
        printf("O resto da divisao eh: %d",res);
        break;
   case 11 : 
        res=pow(n1,n2);
        printf("O resulltado da elevacao eh: %d",res);
        break;
   case 12 :
        res=pow(n2,n1);
        printf("O resulltado da elevacao eh: %d",res);
        break;
    case 0 :
        system("exit");
        break;
   default : 
        printf("Valor Invalido!\n");                                                                    
        break;
    }
   }while (opc!=0); 
   return 0;  
}
````

Comment: já tentou `scanf("%d",&opc);`?

Comment: Tire este system("exit"); e deixe o programa encerrar normalmente quando a opção 0 for informada.

Comment: Sem ter a ver com o problema relatado mas nas opções de divisão você está testando se o numerador é zero quando deveria estar testando o denominador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo o que aparenta estar errado é na hora de selecionar a opção, `scanf("%d",opc);` a variavel que estara recebendo valor deve estar com o `&` sendo assim --> `scanf("%d",&opc)`, e você não declarou a biblioteca para usar a função `system("cls")`, no caso seria a `#include <windows>`
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela observação, quebrei bastante a cabeça pensando que era um outro erro de estrutura e realmente o que faltava era o e comercial (&).Valeu pela atenção !!!!